# background image as fixed background

Tags: html, css

I have no idea why my background image is not showing. I can't see the image in dev tools and I'm stumped. It's in the folder and pointing to the right folder. Any help is appreciated! Here is my code:

html:

```
 <body>
<div class="l-head-backImage"></div>

<div class="container">
    <header>
        <h1>This is the Header</h1>
    </header>
</div><!-- container -->
```

css:

```
  .l-head-backImage {
background: url(../images/Seattle.svg) no-repeat center center fixed;
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are telling it to cover the div; however, the div has no actual size because it has no content in. Therefore, you need to specify a width and height of the div so the image actually has something to cover.

Example with your code and a random dog picture: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QVXpS/)

CSS

```
 .l-head-backImage {
     background: url(../images/Seattle.svg) no-repeat center center fixed;
     -webkit-background-size: cover;
     -moz-background-size: cover;
     -o-background-size: cover;
     background-size: cover;
     height: 300px;
     width: 300px;
  }
```

Comment: Tried it and it's still not working. It looks like the image is being pushed above the page. I'm using Skeleton Grid. I don't know if that info is relevant to this problem. Thanks for the help.

Comment: If the image is being pushed, maybe you have it in a wrapper that is styled with margins?  I won't be of help with Skeleton Grid, but you can see in the js fiddle that the image will at least show if you give it width and height.